# How to get a value of associative array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an associative array in PHP that looks like this

**input array**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11304
                [price] => 5
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1234
                [price] => 10
            )

    )
```

How do I access the value for 'id' and 'price'?

**I've tried**

```
foreach ($final_atas as $key =>$value) {
    echo 'key ----------'.$key.'<br>'; // output 0 and 1
    echo 'price ----------'.$value['price'].'<br>'; // output 5 and 10
    echo 'price ----------'.$value['id'].'<br>';//getting error undefined index id
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($value);
    echo '</pre>'; 
}
```

they all return only price value not id and throwing error ***Notice: Undefined index: id***

```
id --------
price -------- 5
id --------
price -------- 10
Array
(
    [id] => 11304
    [price] => 5
)
Array
(
    [id] => 12034
    [price] => 10
)
```

expected result

```
id --------  11304
price -------- 5
id --------   1234
price -------- 10
```

**var_dump**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "11304"
    ["price"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1234"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a `var_dump($final_atas)` please, likely there is an odd byte in there somewhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have updated my question please check and help me

Comment: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "11304"
    ["price"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1234"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
}

Comment: Unpossible!!!!!

Comment: i m not getting value of id while i am getting value of price

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id, while i am getting id in var_dump please check my updated question

Comment: try var_dump on $value inside the loop

Comment: @Nate please check once var_dum($value); inside loop

array(2) { ["id"]=> string(5) "11304" ["price"]=> string(1) "5" } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(5) "12034" ["price"]=> string(2) "10" }

Comment: This makes no sense

Comment: That seems like the value of $final_atas, and not what $value is inside the foreach loop.

Comment: @Nate i am checking array_key_exist but its showing key not exist while i am getting in var_dump. 

    if(array_key_exists('id', $value)){
        echo 'key exist';
        echo $value['id'].'<br>';
    } else{
        echo 'key does not exist';
    }

Comment: Printing what $value is inside the loop may help. I made this sample code. Maybe it will help. https://pastebin.com/zVdJbSwi

Comment: check once updated question

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but in a new fresh file

```php
$final_atas = [
    [
        'id' => 11304,
        'price' => 5,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1234,
        'price' => 10
    ]
];

foreach ($final_atas as $key =>$value) {
    echo 'key ----------'.$key.'<br>'; // output 0 and 1
    echo 'price ----------'.$value['price'].'<br>'; // output 5 and 10
    echo 'price ----------'.$value['id'].'<br>';//getting error undefined index id
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($value);
    echo '</pre>'; 
}
```

This will most likely work, I copied the same foreach loop you provided.

I believe that you are using an SQL query to get the data, in which case, please update the question with the query you are trying and the table structure in database.

Answer (score 0):

Below, `$a` contains the first element of the nested array and `$b` contains the second element.

```
$array = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
];

foreach ($array as list($a, $b)) {
    // $a contains the first element of the nested array,
    // and $b contains the second element.
    echo "A: $a; B: $b\n";
}
```